# I can't get data from a table using 'fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)'

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo

Why does `fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` not work properly? How can I get the data I want from the table without a `foreach` loop? I have used the `$statement` variable before to prepare/execute another query. Could this be the problem?

```
try
{
    $database = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=youdonotneedtoknow;charset=utf8', 'youdonotneedtoknow', 'youdonotneedtoknow');
    $database -> setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $database -> setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

    //Read
    $statement = $database -> prepare ('SELECT * FROM edit');
    $statement -> execute ();
    while ($row = $statement -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $windowTitle = $row ['windowTitle'];
        $bodyBackgroundColour = $row ['bodyBackgroundColour'];
        $divisionBackgroundColour = $row ['divisionBackgroundColour'];
    }
}
catch (PDOException $exception)
{
    die ('Error: ' . $exception -> getMessage () . '<br><br>' . 'Por favor diríjase a "index.php" en este mismo directorio y contacte a su administrador.');
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're not getting an exception. Do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($row)`, what do you get?

Comment: I get `Array
(
    [id] => windowTitle
    [content] => a
)
Array
(
    [id] => bodyBackgroundColour
    [content] => #000000
) //Etc...`  Which I assume is from the previous query.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? You don't need a `foreach` loop, the `while` loop you have is fine.

Comment: Which you assume is from the previous query...?

Comment: @Barmar: Well, when I cannot display the data from `$windowTitle`, `$bodyBackgroundColour` or `$divisionBackgroundColour`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `show create table edit`?

Comment: I think you're confused about the schema of the `edit` table. It looks like `windowTitle` and `bodyBackgroundColour` are values in the table, not column names.

Comment: @Barmar - That's what I was about to say.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Indeed, as I said in the question, I had run another prepare/execute using the same `$statement` variable. I am sorry if I am horribly mistaken in interpreting the data I posted two messages back.

Comment: No, you've overwritten those variables in the block you have above. There isn't any reason you'd still be retaining values from some previous part of the script with the same variable names.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, they are values. The column names are `id` and `content`. I want `$windowTitle` to have the value of `content` where `id` is `windowTitle`, in the table.

Comment: I see where the `for` loop bit comes from. You want to access the values as key/value pairs from the database, not as individual (separate) columns. You can't. You have to look into the array and see what the `id` is and match that to the variable. You could use a `switch()` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
while ($row = $statement -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    switch ($row['id']) {
        case 'windowTitle':
            $windowTitle = $row ['value'];
            break;
        case 'bodyBackgroundColour':
            $bodyBackgroundColour = $row['value'];
            break;
        case 'divisionBackgroundColour':
            $divisionBackgroundColour = $row['value'];
            break;
    }
}
```

You could also use variable variables:

```
while ($row = $statement -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ${$row['id']} = $row['value'];
}
```